# How to hide part of the element which comes beneath the absolutely positioned element?

Tags: html, css

For example we have class `a` and `b`, and following is the markup

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  This is class a
</div>

<div class="b">
  class b
</div>
```

Is there a way so that the part of class `a` that is being overlapped by class `b` can be hidden completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a background to the `.b`. Since there is no relation between both elements, I don't think there is another way.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  This is class a
</div>

<div class="b">
  class b
</div>
```

Comment: @Johannes well true but i prefer to leave some space to doubt as we don't know .. maybe someone will come with something we don't expect :) even if i don't see any other way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question... but if your goal is to make "b" fully opaque in covering up "a", then you might get the flexibility you're looking for by using the :before and :after pseudo-elements to act like separate layers of "b."
https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/

Or if you're just having trouble getting "b" to be on top of "a", make sure that "b" has a z-depth greater than a.